# npm run script causes Windows Script Host error

Tags: npm

I a trying to use npm to minify javascript.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "minifyjs": "minifyJs",
    "minifycss": "minifyCss",
    "minifyhtml": "minifyHtml"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-css": "^3.4.19",
    "html-minifier": "^3.0.2",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

and my minifyJs script is :

```
var uglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
var fs = require('fs');

var result = uglifyJS.minify(['src/main1.js', 'src/main2.js'], {
    compress: {
        drop_console: true,
        unused: true
    }
});
fs.writeFileSync('dist/minifyJs.js', result.code);
```

When I call npm run minifyjs I get the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong - btw this was working on another machine.....

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The entries under `scripts` are commands that are run by NPM. They are not simply paths to JavaScript files.

You need to tell NPM to run your JavaScript tasks using `node`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "minifyjs": "node minifyJs",
  "minifycss": "node minifyCss",
  "minifyhtml": "node minifyHtml"
},
...
```

Comment: That did the trick. Many thanks!! I must have spent 2 hours on this reinistalling and what not....Much appreciated