# node.js file fail to compile error 800A03EA under Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js

After downloading [node js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and installing for windows 10 (x64). Accepted all the defaults.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v
v12.13.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v
6.12.0
```

Then copied their "hello world" [example](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) to run it to a file node.js

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

moved the prompt location to the folder where the file is and tried to run the command

```
node node.js
```

I get an error popup window:

[image]

I am at loss, what did I not follow correctly? and How to get the node server running.
I am running as a user not as an admin.
Thanks

Comment: ```server.on('error', function (e) { console.log(e); });``` can you add this line and check error ? just below server.listen

Comment: why is it running with Microsoft JScript? that is not node, and it hasn't been supported in like a decade.

Comment: I am not sure why Microsoft JScript is running or what to make of it. @Raju tried that but same error happened.

Comment: JScript is Microsoft's old version of JS that was in Internet Explorer (not in Edge) and JScript is also available for scripting in windows, but it's legacy. The reason JScript gives you a syntax error is that it doesn't have a lot of modern JS stuff like `const` and it also doesn't have node APIs that you're using... So the problem is your environment is somehow messed up and this script is running with JScript instead of node.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936885/npm-run-script-causes-windows-script-host-error

Comment: works on linux , yeah may be chris is right, hey @ChrisRollins what if he is working in severral projects simultaneously so he have to apply this tweak for every project he create ? this solution doesnot seems feasible

Comment: There is probably something globally configured wrong because I can run node scripts on windows without any issue.

Comment: hey can you rename your file , node.js to some other thing, ppl got this resolved by doing so

Comment: @Raju Yes. that worked. renamed it app.js

Comment: i think when the default name is node.js it always  executes Microsoft's obsolescent WSH (Windows Script Host) JavaScript engine (JScript) rather than Node.exe

Answer (score -2):

you have installed wrong version of node i.e of x64 bit and you computer is of 32 bit please download the nodejs appropriate to your computer type i would suggest uninstall node and download node of 32 bit, it will definitely work...

Comment: I replaced the file contents with your code but the same error happened.

Comment: i changed the answer do try

Comment: @RolstanD'souza https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668556/node-js-file-fail-to-compile-error-800a03ea-under-windows-10/58668589#comment103639855_58668556